# Adding white list to SecurityFilterChain in Spring Boot 3.01 and Azure AD 5.1

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory

I'm attempting to following Microsoft's instructions for [Protecting a resource server/API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/spring-boot-starter-for-azure-active-directory-developer-guide?tabs=SpringCloudAzure5x#protect-a-resource-serverapi) in a Java Spring Boot 3.1 project using Azure AD 5.1. Unfortunately though, I'm not able to `permitAll()` for certain endpoints while ensuring others are authorized with a Role or Scope. In the cases I've tried, either both will be unauthorized, or both will be permitted.

Would anyone be able to help me identify where the issue might be?

**Gradle dependencies:**

```
implementation 'com.azure.spring:spring-cloud-azure-starter-active-directory:5.1.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:3.1.0'
```

**application.properties**

```
# ...
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.enabled=true
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=${client-id}
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.app-id-uri=${app-id-uri}
```

**Example AadOAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class AadOAuth2ResourceServerSecurityConfig {

    private static final String[] ENDPOINT_WHITELIST = {"/api/docs/**" };

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain apiFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.apply(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer())
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/docs/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN") // any other than "/api/docs/**"
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```